# Green Function problem PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Someone can give me tips for solve this PDE, please!

$\frac{d^4G}{dx^4}=\delta(x-x_0)$ with $G(0;x_0)=G(L;x_0)=\frac{dG}{dx}(0;x_0)=\frac{d^2G}{dx^2}(0;x_0)=0$

I do not know how to start this, really I need help for this, sorry for ask this but I do not know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> **The Question**:
>   $\ds{\partiald[4]{\mathrm{G}\pars{x,x_{0}}}{x} = \delta\pars{x - x_{0}}}$.
>   
>   $\ds{\mathrm{G}\pars{0,x_{0}} = \mathrm{G}\pars{L,x_{0}} = \left.\partiald{\mathrm{G}\pars{x,x_{0}}}{x}\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ 0} = \left.\partiald[2]{\mathrm{G}\pars{x,x_{0}}}{x}\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ 0} = 0}$

---

We'll assume $\ds{0 < x_{0} < L}$. When $\ds{x \not= x_{0}}$, the solutions are third degree polynomial. In addition,
\begin{equation}
\left.\partiald[3]{\mathrm{G}\pars{x,x_{0}}}{x}\right\vert_{\ x_{0}^{-}}^{\ x_{0}^{\,+}} = 1\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Then,
\begin{align}
\mathrm{G}\pars{x,x_{0}} & =
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcl}
\ds{A_{-}x^{3} + B_{-}x^{2} + C_{-}x} & \mbox{if} & \ds{x < x_{0}}
\\
\ds{A_{+}\pars{L - x}^{3} + B_{+}\pars{L - x}^{2} + C_{+}\pars{L - x}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{x > x_{0}}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

which already satisfies
$\ds{\mathrm{G}\pars{0,x_{0}} = \mathrm{G}\pars{L,x_{0}} = 0}$. Moreover,
$\ds{\left.\partiald{\mathrm{G}\pars{x,x_{0}}}{x}\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ 0} = 0}$ and
$\ds{\left.\partiald[2]{\mathrm{G}\pars{x,x_{0}}}{x}\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ 0} = 0}$ lead to, respectively, $\ds{C_{-} = 0}$ and $\ds{B_{-} = 0}$ such that
$\ds{\mathrm{G}\pars{x,x_{0}}}$ is reduced to:

\begin{align}
\mathrm{G}\pars{x,x_{0}} & =
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcl}
\ds{A_{-}x^{3}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{x < x_{0}}
\\
\ds{A_{+}\pars{L - x}^{3} + B_{+}\pars{L - x}^{2} + C_{+}\pars{L - x}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{x > x_{0}}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

Also, *continuity* at $\ds{x = x_{0}}$ and the *condition* $\pars{1}$ lead to, respectively:
\begin{align}
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{%
A_{+}\pars{L - x_{0}}^{3} + B_{+}\pars{L - x_{0}}^{2} + C_{+}\pars{L - x_{0}}}
& \ds{=} & \ds{A_{-}x_{0}^{3}} 
\\[3mm] 
\ds{-6A_{+} - 6A_{-}} & \ds{=} & \ds{1}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

which determines two of them in terms of other ones. It means you still need two more conditions to determine *"completely"* $\ds{\mathrm{G}\pars{x,x_{0}}}$ !!!.

Comment: I think the condition (1) implies that $$-6 A_+ - 6 A_- = 1$$

Comment: @RonGordon Thanks. Fixed. I guess I was thinking in the first deriv... "as usual".